# How can i increase a value of an variable passed as an argument to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a `main` function that has the variables `int x` and `int y`.  I am calling a `void` function, `task`, with the addresses of `x` and `y` inthe pointers `int *p1`, `int *p2`, which are the parameters of the function `task`.

Then I try to increase the values contained in `*p1` and `*p2`, to try to change the values of the variable `x` and `y`, since I am increasing the values that are in inside variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void task(int *p1, int *p2)
{
 *p1++;
 *p2++;
 printf("%d\n", *p1);
 printf("%d\n", *p2);
 }

 int main()
 {
  int x = 10;
  int y = 100;

  task(&x, &y);
  printf("%d\n", y);
  printf("%d\n", x);
 }
```

But the values stay the same. Is it possible to change the value of the variables `x` and `y`?

Comment: First red flag should be that the values you print in `task` are wrong.

Comment: Read this [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Compile your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler invoked as`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: I'm not understading how that is relevant @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: @ricardomart: With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you would get a useful warning, then you would improve your C code (e.g. using [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...) to get no warnings at all. You could also use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In all fairness, it is rather embarrassing that gcc does not warn for this code unless you feed it `-Wall`. clang does.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
 *p1++;
 *p2++;
```

to

```
 (*p1)++;
 (*p2)++;
```

In the first case the pointer variables `p1` and `p2` are being incremented, not the values that they point to.

Using parentheses makes it clear that the value is to be incremented, not the pointers themselves.

Comment: Thanks man, that was fast. I should of figure out that the * as no precedense over ++, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Please use

```
(*p1)++;
(*p2)++;
```

The order is different now.
It would be clearer to explain if `task()` is modified as follow

```
void task(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    printf("%p %d\n",p1, *p1);
    printf("%p %d\n",p2, *p2);
    *p1++;
    *p2++;
    printf("%p %d\n",p1, *p1);
    printf("%p %d\n",p2, *p2);
}
```

Try to check pointer address & value, you'll find what you missed.

Comment: Yeah I understand the differences in acessing value and memory, but i was lossing my mind trying to understand why this didnt work, Just did this smaller program to put what i didnt understood, but thanks anyway you we're helpfull

Comment: Glad you got what you need! Sometimes we got stuck in pretty simple things. LOL

Answer (score 2):

here you are just increasing the address when you try to *p1++. here first it's going to p1++ which just increased your address then trying to read the value from the address with `*p1`. thats why it can't print the expected value.

just add parenthesis.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void task(int *p1, int *p2)
{
 (*p1)++;
 (*p2)++;
 printf("%d\n", *p1);
 printf("%d\n", *p2);
 }

 int main()
 {
  int x = 10;
  int y = 100;

  task(&x, &y);
  printf("%d\n", y);
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
 }
```